# unusual chaining of "grep" in the shell

Tags: bash, shell, grep

I stumbled upon a shell instruction which looks odd:
`ls -a | grep ".qmail-" | grep -v "mail" | grep ".mail" > t ; echo $?`
I suspect that the returned value would represent an error. Could anyone confirm  this or explain in which circumstances this instruction would be applied ?

Comment: ...and on a different point, using `ls` programmatically is a bug-prone antipattern; see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs for details and alternate approaches.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first `grep` only allows through lines that contain `qmail` (preceded by any character and followed by a dash, but that is largely immaterial).  The second `grep` strips out lines that contain `mail`, which means every line passed by the first `grep` is deleted by the second.  There's nothing left for the third one to process, so the file `t` will always be empty.  The value for `$?` should be 1, failure, since the third `grep` failed to find any lines that matched its pattern (because it got no lines to process).

It is a mistake.

It is hard to know how to fix it without knowing what it is trying to do.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I was aware that chaining the first 2 `grep` instructions is a mistake but the result was returned by `echo $?` was unclear. Thank you for the explanation

Answer (score 1):

The bash shell (and most other shells) let users use the output of one command as the input of another. This is accomplished with the `|` operator which is called a pipe. So the output of of `ls -a` is fed to `grep ".qmail-"` and so on. The `>` operator sends the output of the command to a file, in this case `t`. So `ls -a | grep ".qmail-" | grep -v "mail" | grep ".mail" > t` lists the contents of a directory and passes the output through successive filters before finally saving the output to the file `t`.

The  semicolon signals the end of a command and allows multiple bash commands to be entered on a single line.

`echo $?` prints out the return value of the last executed command, in this case, `ls -a | grep ".qmail-" | grep -v "mail" | grep ".mail" > t`. By convention, any value besides 0 indicates some sort of error occurred.[The Linux Documentation Project](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html) gives a list of some common exit codes.